# Whats the best recommendation for an open source incident management tool?

Tags: jira

What would be the best recommendation for an open source incident management tool?

Comment: Welcome. There are a few I can recommend. Maybe be add a bit more details on your requirements e.g. platform to run on, web-based or app, industry you want to use it for, etc.